# Google api request only shows the route from origin to destination

Tags: google-maps

I have given google api request:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=58.43299833333334,24.75029833333333&destination=59.4524459,24.9040487&%20waypoints=optimize:true%7C59.436962,24.753574%7C57.77781,26.0473%7C59.4524459,24.9040487%7C59.4524459,24.9040487%7C59.4528068,24.9065196%7C54.7275433,11.4649304%7C59.2967063,24.6589228%7C59.4524459,24.9040487%7C59.4529451,24.9053912%7C59.453479,24.9073259%7C&sensor=false

This request gives me the path in map only from origin to destination.
But i need it for solving Travelling salesman problem with 8 destinations.
Please help. What is the right request for path with multiple waypoints?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in your request you should fix `&%20waypoints=optimize:true`. Remove empty space between & and waypoints, the empty space is URL-encoded as %20.

Comment: Thank you dude you made my day!